# Max-height <img> within container with max-height, inconsistent behavior

Tags: css

I have a container with a max-height defined in pixels, and then an IMG within with a max-height defined in percentage. In Chrome this works as expected, in other browsers the img simply extends beyond the container.

Anyone know which is the proper behavior, and why?

```
<figure>

    <img src="http://images.autostash.com/parts/img/medium/wix/24056.jpg" alt="no picture">     

</figure>

figure {
    max-width: 90px;
    max-height: 90px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
    max-height: 90%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dygerati/wWRJK/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MDN description of the CSS height property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height),

> The  is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly, the value computes to auto. A percentage height
>   on the root element (e.g. ) is relative to the viewport.

As a result, since you have only `max-height` and `min-height` declared, and NOT `height`, the `img` height defaults to `auto`.

Comment: It looks like MDN's description is a lot better than what I found on W3C. So this is either a bug in Chrome, or an intentional break from standards to mitigate issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
figure {
    max-width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Yup, I know this can remedy it, I'm really just curious what is expected in this case.